# Project 3d position on a spheroid to 2D

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have a series of 3D positions (x, y, z) on a spheroid object, how do I project these 3D positions to 2D with d3.js and keep their relative position?
My array is like this:

[{X: 339.34474945068354, Y: 505.363540649415, Z: '187.425979614258'},
{X: 333.741912841797, Y: 445.61164855957054, Z: '185.462127685547'}]

These points are regularly arranged on the quasi-sphere, and I hope their relative positions can be maintained in the mapping.

I don't know what equation should be used in customized D3.js projection. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: What should the final result look like? Will you draw a picture and add it to your question?

Comment: Hi, I already added the expected picture to the question!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link to the image. I updated the question so that the image is inline.

Comment: So do you want all 3 of the squares drawn as output?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, this is my first time using this website. These three squares are the canvas for drawing the 2D positions, for me, the important thing is the 3D to 2D mapping arrangement is accurate.

Comment: I don't know d3.js. But if you are looking for the mathematics for a solution, then maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection will get you started.